# What are the ways to identify a good attribute test while constructing a decision tree?

Tags: decision-trees

I'm working through a decision tree by hand to learn it. From my research, I have found the following three ways of determining which variables to split on:

1. Minimum remaining values - The variable with the fewest legal values is chosen
2. Degree heuristic - The variable with the most constraints on remaining values
3. Least Constraining value - The variable that rules out the fewest remaining values in the remaining variables

Do I have these right? What are some other ways of determining the splits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have mixed up CSP (Constrained Satisfaction Problem) search trees and decision trees:

**CSP search trees**

'Minimum remaining values', 'Degree Heuristic' and 'Least Constraining Value' are used to solve CSPs and not in decision trees (i.e. we are talking symbolic AI here and not a sub-symbolic AI method like decision trees).

However, as far as I know the 'least constraining value' approach is not used to select a variable but after having selected one to choose the order to inspect its values.

So it could go rather like this:

```
1. Choose a variable applying 'minimum remaining values'  
2. If step 1 fails select a variable applying the 'degree heuristic'
3. For the selected variable select its values ordered according to 'least constraining value'
```

Besides the ones you mentioned you could go the really simple route: just pick 'the next' variable or pick randomly.

Also see section 6.3.1 in 'Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach' by Russel and Norvig.

**Decision trees**

In contrast decision trees are a machine learning method. Here you usually choose the best splits for the tree using a greedy algorithm providing the biggest ad-hoc gain (see below list for how to define 'gain'). Typical criteria for the greedy split are:

Classification

- Information gain (based on entropy)
- Gini score
- Classification error (usually not used when building the tree)

Regression

- Squared error

Also see sections 9.2.2 and 9.2.3 in 'The Elements of statistical learning' by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman.